# Automatic shutdown of Pi based on timer

Tags: video, cron, shutdown

I'm looking to have my pi shutdown automatically based on a time interval (rather than the time of day). This is for an art installation and the reason I am turning off the pi is because it will connected to a projector, and to get the projector to shutoff, it needs to not be receiving a signal. I've tried editing cron with the follow command to no success:

@reboot shutdown -h +5

This was the test sample, my goal is have it shutdown after 3 hours. This is to save lamp life as the sculpture will run continuously, 24/7. I have a timer switch connected to the pi and projector that will turn it back on automatically.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK the Pi will continue to output video even when shutdown. You need to remove power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a couple of mistakes, all par for the course. Let's step through this, get it working, and hopefully learn one other trick to help you help yourself in the future:

First, the "other trick": When you run a command from the terminal, your error messages `stderr` go to the terminal, and you see them immediately. When you run a command as a `cron` user, those error messages go "somewhere else", and you don't see them when the script execution is attempted. However, you can "redirect" the `stderr` to a file for post-op review later. I've modified your command to add the `stderr` redirection as follows:

```
@reboot shutdown -h +5  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

Copy that over your current `crontab` entry. Then save your `crontab` file, and reboot:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

*NOTE: The `$` is not an input, it's part of the command line in the shell.*

Five minutes later, you'll note that your RPi has not halted, but a file containing an error message is now available here: `/home/pi/cronjoblog`

Inspecting this file, you'll see the following:

```
$ cat cronjoblog
/bin/sh: 1: shutdown: not found  
$
```

This message simply means that the shell couldn't find `shutdown`. It couldn't find it because the `cron` user has a different $PATH than you do as user `pi`. The solution is easy enough - simply give the full file spec for `shutdown`:

```
@reboot /sbin/shutdown -h +5  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

If you modify your `crontab` file, then reboot again to run this, the file `/home/pi/cronjoblog` will inform you of the other mistake you've made: `shutdown` requires root privileges, i.e. `sudo`. I'll skip the intervening trial-and-error process (but you shouldn't), and show a functional `crontab` entry here:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -h +5  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

That should do it... let us know if you have other issues, and we'll address those.

Comment: When adding the line by running `sudo crontab -e` you don't need to put sudo to your crontab.

Comment: @jake: What do you suppose the advantage is for running `sudo crontab -e` vs. running `shutdown` as root?

Comment: Nothing, if you are allowed to `sudo` without a password!

Comment: @jake: AFAIK, user `pi` needs no pwd for `sudo`

Comment: Thanks! This worked. As a stubborn guy who never asks for directions, I have been struggling with this for a long time.