# Automatically shutdown Pi 104 hours after booting?

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, shutdown

I have a project where I'd like to plug in (to power) the Raspberry Pi, have it start running a Python program to write data to a USB stick, and shut itself down after 104 hours. It will NOT be connected to a network.

For example. I plug in the Pi at 9:00 AM on Monday morning, it runs all week, and shuts itself down at 5:00 PM on Friday.

I thought about doing this with cron as described in this entry...
[Automatic shutdown of Pi based on timer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93763/automatic-shutdown-of-pi-based-on-timer)
...but given that the Pi will not be connected to a network, I'm not sure if this will work.

Any ideas on how to handle the automatic shutting down? Thanks!

Note: I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Rasbian Buster.

Comment: Add an `@reboot` line in a crontab with `sudo shutdown -h +‭6240‬` that will activate in 60*104 minutes from now.

Comment: Might need to give the full path to shutdown.

Comment: Thank you, Dougie and Joan, for the replies! It sounds like this is the line I need to add to cron:
`@reboot /sbin/shutdown -h +6240`

Comment: An alternative to `cron` is the [`at command`](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-at-command-on-linux) for one-time tasks that you want to run at a specific time. Running `shutdown` with a delay is a good answer for your purpose though. But I am wondering if your PI has a realtime clock backup up by battery since it will not be able to do network time synchronization. Then `at` may not be a good option.

Comment: @Anonymous, I do not have a real time clock on the Pi. But I will take a look at the `at` command in general though. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You could use a systemd timer here too, but crontab is probably the simplest.

Comment: I would suggest the DH3231 cheapy US$1 real time clock module: (1) https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32833136577.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.76937940VSQE7O&algo_pvid=6016cf0b-0718-489d-84ee-87c26c023f05&algo_expid=6016cf0b-0718-489d-84ee-87c26c023f05-5&btsid=0ab6f8ad15835549546142439e1b1f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_, (2) https://www.adafruit.com/product/4282.

Comment: Well shucks. I tried both of these commands (using a shorter time of 5 minutes for testing), and neither worked.
`@reboot /sbin/shutdown -h +5`
`@reboot sudo shutdown -h +‭5`

Answer (score 2):

Run `shutdown` command each `104h`.

```
0 */104 * * * /sbin/shutdown
```

It will run the command every `104h`.

1. When you turn it on, the counter is `0h`.
2. Wait for 104 hours.
3. Then the counter gonna be `104h`.
4. Finally, it will `shutdown` the raspberry pi.

After you turns the raspberry pi on, the counter would be `0h`. Again will follow step 1 to 4.